# ValueError: Attempt to convert a value with an unsupported type to a Tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, indexing, tensor

I'm a beginner and I'm learning, I found this project on GitHub and worked with it but in a part of the codes there is a problem that I cant's solve it, I think it's not hard to solve it but I don't know the bases behind Tensor and Keras, so I'm so thankful of people who help me to pass this problem and finish this project well.

This is the source of project [Recommender System](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10N5r8eLyUVy_7roubDcWeEEpHZuxK8O4#scrollTo=837BDZhWDEAx)

This is the part where I ran into trouble:

`brute_force_layer.index( candidates_corpus_dataset.batch(100).map(movielens_retrieval_model.candidate_model), candidates_corpus_dataset )`

---

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in 
> 1 brute_force_layer.index(
> 2     candidates_corpus_dataset.batch(100).map(movielens_retrieval_model.candidate_model),
> 3     candidates_corpus_dataset
> 4 )
>
> 2 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
> 100       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
> 101   ctx.ensure_initialized()
> 102   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
> 103
> 104
>
> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<MapDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 32), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.MapDataset'>) to a Tensor.

.

Comment: link is broken, please update the notebook

Comment: I'v updated it my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the dataset as follow

```
brute_force_layer.index_from_dataset(candidates_corpus_dataset.batch(128).map(lambda x: (x, movielens_retrieval_model.candidate_model(x))))
```